# RabbitMQ consumer should listen through a routing key instead of QueueName

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I have created a publisher with the below code example.

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
    conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
        var args = process.argv.slice(2);
        var routingkey = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : 'anonymous.info';
        var keys = routingkey.split(".")

        var exchange = keys[0];
        queueName = keys[1];
        var msg = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'Hello World!';

        console.log("Exchange---------------------" , exchange);
        console.log("routingkey-------------------", routingkey);
        console.log("queueName-------------------" , queueName);

        queueName = exchange;

        ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {durable: false});
        ch.assertQueue(queueName, {exclusive: false, durable: false}, false);

        ch.bindQueue(queueName, exchange, routingkey);

        ch.publish(exchange, routingkey, new Buffer(msg));
        console.log(" [x] Sent %s: '%s'", routingkey, msg);
    });

    setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);
});
```

Based on the above publisher:

`exchange : notification ::: 
 queueName : notification ::: 
 routingkey : ['notification.addworker' , 'notification.getworker',.....]`

So, that i am able to publish messages to a unique queue Name using binding with multiple routing keys.

Here my problem, I am unable to consume messages based on routing key because the messages are bind to queue while publish itself.

Suggest if i did wrong the above code.

ConsumerCode:

```
 var args = process.argv.slice(2);
 amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
     conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
         var ex = 'notification';
         var args = process.argv.slice(2);
         var routingkey = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : 'anonymous.info';
         var keys = routingkey.split(".")
         var exchange = keys[0];
         var queueName = exchange;
         ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'direct', {durable: false});

         ch.assertQueue(exchange, {exclusive: false, durable:false}, function(err, q) {
             console.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C');
             ch.bindQueue(queueName, ex, routingkey);
             console.log("Exchange---------------------" , exchange);
             console.log("routingkey-------------------", routingkey);
             console.log("queueName-------------------" , queueName);
             ch.consume(queueName, function(msg) {
                 console.log(" [x] %s:'%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
             }, {noAck: true});
         });
     });
 });
```

Consumer is not able to filter the messages based on routing key.

Looking for suggestion where i make it wrong. I am insisted to use topic.

Thanks for patience.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in case you're interested in my 2 cents... what I do is in the publish command I add some reply information:

```
ch.publish(exchange, send_key, new Buffer(message), { correlationId: corrId, replyTo: q.queue });
```

Where the q.queue comes from the assetQueue callback, and you can specify the reply queue.

This can then be consumed...

```
ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {...}
```

Not sure this answers your question exactly, I haven't yet managed to eliminate the queue name yet, I'm still a beginner myself.